# Incrementing an integer by +1 and adding to string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to create an integer that starts at 0000 and increments by +1 (0001 etc) and then adds it to a string until the number reaches 9999. How could i do this?

Comment: By writing some code to do it. If you have trouble with what you've written, *then* ask here and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: You want the string `"000000010002...9999"`? What have you done so far?

Comment: No, i want (0000, 0001, 0002, 0003 - 9999)

Comment: I don't think it's possible, but you best bet might be an array!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stated that you want to add them to a URL so the way to do it would be:

```
url = "thisisanamazingurl{0:0>4}" # insert your URL instead of thisisanamazingurl

for i in range(10000):
    tempurl = url.format(i)
    print(tempurl)   # instead of print you should do whatever you need to do with it
```

This works because `:0>4` fills the "input string" with leading zeros if it's shorter than 4 characters.

For example with `range(10)` this prints:

```
thisisanamazingurl0000
thisisanamazingurl0001
thisisanamazingurl0002
thisisanamazingurl0003
thisisanamazingurl0004
thisisanamazingurl0005
thisisanamazingurl0006
thisisanamazingurl0007
thisisanamazingurl0008
thisisanamazingurl0009
```

or if you want to store them as a list:

```
lst = [url.format(i) for i in range(10000)]
```

Comment: I have a URL , i want to add this value into the URL after every increment of +1.

Comment: It outputs every number onto the URL, i want it to save a different URL for every value. For example, google.com/0000.html, and then google.com/0001.html and so on.

Comment: @MattCasey please also edit your question to reflect what you said here and insert your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in range(10000):
    print(str(x).rjust(4, '0'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num = ""

for number in range(10000):
    num = num + str('%04d' % number)

print num
```

This will iterate through every number between 0 and 9999 and append it to the `num` string. The `'%04d'` bit forces it to use 4 numeric places with the leading zeros.

(As an aside, you can change the ending number by changing the value of the number in the `range` function.)

Comment: OP doesn't want the 40KB string.

Answer (score -1):

Since you want to add it to a string, I am going to assume you want the type of the 4 digit number as string .

So you can do(python3.x) :

```
string=''

for x in range(10000):

    digit= '0'*(4- len(str(x)) + str(x) 
    string+=digit
```

Comment: (1) max range s/b 10K not 1K (2) don't need both  `x` and `_`

Comment: Thanks for bringing that to notice